# How to update state after an API call completes and before the component has rendered

Tags: json, reactjs, rest, api, mern

I have a function which makes an API call to fetch an item and then stores that object array in a state variable 'data'. But the variable is not getting updated. On logging, it shows an empty array. On logging the API call result, I get the required response. That means i'm getting the data from the call but just can't put that in my 'data' variable.

Here's the function

```
componentWillMount(){
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
    const itemId = parseInt(this.state.id);
    Axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/item/getitem/${itemId}`)
    .then(res => {
        this.setState({
            data: res.data
        })
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: Try console.log(this.state.data) in the render and you will get the updated state

Comment: Doing side-effect in `componentWillMount` is not suggested, please use `componentDidMount`, please read https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html for more info.

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb I tried that. It still shows an empty array

Comment: @karianpour I want to populate the 'data' variable before the component is rendered as I am using that in the render part. So wouldn't that be interfered with if i use componentDidMount?

Comment: you can just set default value of your data state as empty array.

Comment: @AbhishekYadav, just consider it in the render function, that for the first render there is no data (i.e. by showing a Spinner or 'loading...'), then when the data arrives, run `this.setState...` by using `setState` the component will rerender and this time it will have the data, and you may use it. Take look at the sample (here)[https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html]

Comment: @karianpour yeah i solved it by using a 'loading' variable in my state which is true by default. When I receive the data, I changed the loading variable to false which rerendered the component. In the render method, I checked if loading is true. If it is, i return a div with "Loading" text. If not, I returned my normal component. This solved the problem.